# Fortran 90 Functions

Tags: fortran

what is the equivalent function of "i in range" used in python (creates a sequence of numbers between a and b), on Fortran?
Same for "append" (appends a passed object into the existing list)

How to create an array with some boxex that should not be full?

Thank you!

Comment: _what is the equivalent function of "i in range" used in python (creates a sequence of numbers between a and b), on Fortran? Same for "append" (appends a passed object into the existing list)_ That seems rather basic, have you done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

> equivalent function of "i in range"

The implied do-loop is what you are looking for

```pascal
(f(i), i=1, n)
```

> Same for "append" (appends a passed obj into the existing list)

The list in python which can dynamically grow has no direct comparison in fortran.

As @IanBush has pointed out: There is an alternative using `allocatable` but note that it reallocates and copies the whole array *every* time

```pascal
integer, allocatable :: arr(:)

arr = [1, 2]
arr = [arr, 3]
```

You might want to think about implementing your own derived type which can grow exponentially. Something similar to [std::vector in c++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

> How to creat an array with some boxex that should not be full?

Elaboration as given by a comment:

> In this grid there are some black boxes that should not be filled and i dont know how to do this, there are also some boxes with two numbers and i dont know how to do this either.

You could just define boolean arrays for that (I assume you don't really care about memory consumption)

```pascal
program main
  implicit none

  integer              :: n, i, j
  integer, allocatable :: grid(:,:,:)
  logical, allocatable :: unused(:,:), double(:,:)

  n = 10
  allocate (grid(2,n,n))
  allocate (unused(n,n), source=.true.)
  allocate (double(n,n), source=.false.)

  ! set values
  unused(1, 2) = .false.

  do i = 1, n
    do j = 1, n
      if (unused(i,j)) cycle

      if (double(i,j)) then
        ! use values grid(1,i,j), grid(2,i,j)

      else
        ! only use value grid(1,i,j)
      end if
    end do
  end do
end program
```

Comment: Well .... If a is a 1D array you can say a = [ a, value ]

Comment: @IanBush This would reallocate the whole array and copy it. To the programmer this feels like the same but is inefficient. Not sure if IKRAM was looking for that. I will include that in my answer anyway

Comment: Sometimes, even often, efficiency isn't important (sacrilege I know)  and clarity is what matters. But if you need something that is dynamically resized at runtime you are going to get the reallocation blues, whatever the language - though MOVE_ALLOC can help keep it to a minimum in Fortran

Comment: As performance is quite often the reason to choose fortran I think it makes sense to point it out here. A derived type which dynamically resizes an underlying array using _exponentially larger sizes_ is something nice to have.

Comment: thank you so much... for the last question here is the context: i want to write  a code that enable me to solve the kakuro grid in Fortran. In this grid there are some black boxes that should not be filled and i dont know how to do this, there are also some boxes with two numbers and i dont know how to do this either.

Comment: Oh i see thank you so much! what about a box that half of it should not be filled and the other half has a number?

Comment: easy way to got would be to add more dimensions to to grid, i.e. `grid(5,n,n)` and each spcifies a number in a different corner. or add more logical arrays.

Comment: typically in OOP you would define a derived type for a box which would handle all that for you. that would be nicer...